# I created a new node project and package.json did not upload to Git

Tags: node.js, git, github

I did the following

```
npm init
```

Then I added it to my Repository. By

```
git status
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git push origin master
```

Now I visit my repo and my `package.json` is NOT there. Am I doing something wrong?

I have a gitignore it looks like the following

```
# Logs
logs
*.log

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directory
# Commenting this out is preferred by some people, see
# https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-faq.html#should-i-check-my-node_modules-folder-into-git-
node_modules

# Users Environment Variables
.lock-wscript
```

---

```
 git status
```

reveals the following

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .DS_Store

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "FXTrader",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A web application to show data about Foreign Currency.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/username/FXTrader"
  },
  "author": "Me MySelf",
  "license": "NONE",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/username/FXTrader/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/username/FXTrader"
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you type git status?

Comment: Also, do you have a .gitignore file?

Comment: What do you mean, "When I visit my repo, package.json is not there?" You log in GitHub, or what?

Comment: Which version of Git are you using?

Comment: Can you share your package.json as well? Also, make some small change to it, then do git status, commit and push. Share the output of each

Comment: @MudassirRazvi 1.9.3 -Shamoon the package.json file has been uploaded

Comment: Make some small changes and commit again, adding to your post with the output of each step